# How to set different blog post meta tags in a react express web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am creating a blog using react and express. Since there are different blog posts, there are different meta tags like title description, og tags etc. How do I set the title and other og tags dynamically so that according to the post id, it fetches the required title, description, og image and others from the server and displays them.

Tried react helmet but the changes made by it are not accessible by crawlers.

What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: Are you doing SSR?

Comment: Right now I am doing SSR and am able to load meta tags according to the different pages. But I was wondering which is the more optimal way.

Comment: @Bora Can you share how did you implement SSR with react-helmet? The online documentation is not of great help